# Optimising a naive piece of code for counters in C. Need a better solution

Tags: c

I am using three counters c1, c2 and c3 in my code for one of the processes in the system. At certain points I need to trigger each of the counters and end it at a particular point(targetc1,targetc2,targetc3). So I am using three flags cf1,cf2 and cf3 to check if the counter flag is set ON whenever my process is triggered and then checking against the counter target if it reached the end point. Is there a better way to do it rather than using three flags? I may need to use more counters in future in my code but it shouldnt exceed some 6 counters I presume.
Code snippet is given below for p1 process to explain my problem.

```
/*P1 process variables*/
static int c1,c2,c3;
static int targetc1,targetc2,targetc3;
static int cf1,cf2,cf3;

p1startingfunction()
{
    int a;
    if(cf1 == 1)
    {
    c1++;
    if(c1==targetc1)
        /*counter reached do something*/
        c1trigger();
    }
    if(cf2 == 1)
    {
    c2++;
    if(c2==targetc2)
        /*counter reached do something*/
        c2trigger();
    }
   if(cf3 == 1)
    {
    c3++;
    if(c3==targetc3)
        /*counter reached do something*/
        c3trigger();
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose the integer overflow is to be ignored, or didn't you consider that?

Comment: Do the triggers reset the counters? If so, then it might make some sense to initialize the counters to the target values and decrement them instead, then call your triggers when they reach 0. Although, with optimization, that might not end up making a difference. Then put all the counters in an array as suggested in the answers below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is still lots of room for improvement with this, but this answer is specifically for minimizing code repetition.

With that said, you could use arrays:

```
/*P1 process variables*/
static int c[3];
static int targetc[3];
static int cf[3];
static void (*ctrigger[3])(void);

p1startingfunction()
{
    int a, i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (cf[i] == 1) {
            c[i]++;
            if (c[i] == targetc[i]) {

                /* counter reached do something */
                ctrigger[i]();                    
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Or you could use a struct that looks something like:

```
struct counter {
    int c;
    int target;
    int f;
    void (*trigger)(void);
};
```

And then create an array of structs.

```
struct counter counters[3];
```